# Gallery slider with photo tagging feature

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Are there any existing open-source packages of horizontal gallery slider (with JavaScript and jQuery) with photo-tagging feature that can be used in a personal portfolio?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below link it has different demos for your requirement

http://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/image%20tagging/